# Is there a possibility to move multiple objects to a deferred origin, but maintaining the space between them?

Tags: modeling, transforms

Using "set Geometry to Origin" doesn't do the last thing. I have a landscape and when i do this all the objects are moved to the origin, but e.g. the flowers or trees are in a completely different position (in the terrain).

Comment: It should work with multiple objects. Can you upload the .blend file please?

Comment: It works just the same as with one object - you select them, and use either Origin to Geometry or to Center of Mass.

Comment: I've just tried it with a different file and it suddenly worked. I think there was just something wrong with it (I've edited the question for another one i had (and wanted to ask it a bit later)). But is there a possibility to move these objects to the deferred origin, but maintaining the space between them? Using "set Geometry to Origin" doesn't do the last thing.

Comment: `Shift`+`S` > *Selection to Cursor (Offset)* ? (with objects selected and cursor properly placed)

Comment: parent them to an empty ( or one of them ) and move the empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are detailed instructions on how to shift multiple objects as if they were one. I am using a house models that is made up of separate models.

- **Go to Select Menu**
- **Select All by Type**
- **Select Mesh**
  [image]
- **Press Shift + Ctrl + Alt + C then “Origin to Geometry”**
  [image]
- **Press Shift + S select “Cursor to center”**
  [image]
- **Press Shift + S select “Selection to Cursor (offset)”**
  [image]